# Adjusting Nav Media Queries in Twitter Bootstrap 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, nav

This is probably a pretty straight-forward answer, yet I'm unable to find out a solution.  I'm building a site off of Twitter Bootstrap 2 and the client has asked that the 6 menu links within the nav at the top be centered and spaced across the entire container.  When I do this and then begin to shrink the browser window, a couple of the menu items begin to stack on top of each other, creating a taller nav bar.  The only way I've been able to find a solution to avoid this is by having the nav go straight to the collapsable menu as it does starting at 724px.

What do I need to do in order to have the menu at 940px be the same as 724px, and not 1170px?  I'm also having some padding issues that I need to override when the collapsable menu is present, but I can start another question log for this.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us your style code please ? CSS maybe ?

Comment: Honestly, I'm going straight off of the Bootstrap download from github.  I haven't made any changes really to the stylesheets, other than removing the brand portion of the nav and spacing the nav links accordingly across the container.  I just need to find out how to make the collapsable nav appear at the 940px media queries rather than the regular nav that is the same as at 1170px.

Comment: C'mon...this has to be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, my friends...I have answered my own question.  I wasn't 100% sure how to deal with the media queries, but I figured out that you can do the min / max for different resolution sizes in the main.css.

Thanks, me! :)